# Use Case Diagram - Web Server(external) or just Admin?

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I am making a Use Case Diagram for my application which involves verifying users.The verification process involves an external web server.Along with this i have admin as an actor.Should i include Web server(actor) or should i just leave it as a use case for admin?
[My Use Case Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phagt.png)

Comment: could you publish your diagram ?

Comment: here's the link--- https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAGRX.png

Answer (score 1):

Actor: external element which is involved in a use case. It could be a human or "whatever".

So the first point to know is : is this web server included or not in your system ?

If the web server is in your system, it could not be an actor, if it is external to your system and participates to a use case, this is an actor.

A use case is a BehavioredClassifier which may have InterfaceRealizations, and owns a set of Behaviors. (p 172)

A use case is a set of actions, it would be strange that a server could be a use case.

The arrow between actor is not the right one. The bullet near the actor is unknown for me.

There are primarry and secondary actors (web server) but we can not which is what.

The extend is not usefull since View Alternatives is used by one use case only. And this is not the right arrow for extend (a dash one with open arrow)

You can add some generalizations relation between Care taker and doctor and Care taker and Chemist : they activate the same set of use cases.

Your Admin manages users only, he can't do any actions of the normal users. Is it right ? In some context Admin gets all rights.

Then you can read a lot's of post about UC and the fact that a UC does not model a function.

Comment: No.Web Server is an external to my system.(mentioned in the title)

Comment: also,the use case i am saying is the verification of users.Now will this be the use case of web server or  the admin can do this too?

Comment: Please publish your own diagram and we will comment it. For a use case, I define a primary actor always or this is a a use case triggered by an event (like scheduled task) and you can define secondary actors as you need. A secondary actor is an actor which participates to the use but does not activate it.

Comment: Why can't doctors view prescriptions? Also, I'm not sure I understand what `Verification` is. If it is what the server does to verify logins, then the other actors don't interact with it. Also in that case, it should have an `includes` relationship with `Login`. If the verification takes place during registration, then it should have an `includes` relationship with that as well. Finally, your `<<extends>>` needs to have an open arrow at the `Search Medicine` end.

Comment: My problem with the "validation" use case is that it is not worded as an action. It should probably be something like "validate prescription" to better show what it does. Use cases are actions that provide a benefit to the initiating user and, as such, should be expressed with verbs.

Comment: I agree that the "view alternatives" extend is not useful, but for a different reason: it is not used by any actor. Extend means "I do everything that is in the extended use case and more. If there are no actors that need to do more, then it is not needed. Note that an "extend" is _not_ a "use." or an "include" (which would be closest to a "use").
Also, you should try to have all your "primary/active actors on one side of the diagram and all the reactive secondary/reactive ones on the other side - this provides a better overview of their functions with regard to the use case.